# Running a second PHP script while keeping the client on same page

Tags: php

I'm creating a app that requires me to run a second php script while the first script is still running.

I'm new to php programing so I'm sure there's a simple function I can use that I'm just not aware of.

Looking forward to any help...

Shane

Comment: `exec('php path/to/the/script');`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Thanks @k102 I think I'll use that. I also asked a couple questions on PaulP.R.O Answer that I could use some help on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to PHP I'm guessing you're looking for the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) (and [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)/[require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)) language constructs which will execute another PHP script as if it is part of the current script.

Otherwise if you want it to run as a separate process look into [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), or [backticks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php). If you need the other PHP script to run as a background process make sure to redirect stdout somewhere (a file or maybe /dev/null if you don't need it) so that your currently executing script doesn't have to wait for it to finish to continue executing.

Comment: absolutely what i think he wants.

Comment: I think the exec operator will work great, but if I need to pass var. how would I do that? Also will the first script continue or will it wait for a response?

Comment: @ShaneE.Bryan Are you familiar with a linux shell (and running PHP ON Linux)? exec takes in a command if you want to pass arguments to that command you can just append them to the command string separated by whitespace like `'/usr/bin/php ' . $filename` to run a php script whose name is stored in the variable `$filename` (If your php interpreter is located in /usr/bin/php). You probably also want to escape your arguments with escapeshellarg. The script will wait for a response unless you redirect stdout somewhere like: `exec('/usr/bin/php ' . escapeshellarg($filename) . ' > /dev/null');`

Comment: So if I have multiple var. i would code it like this     <code> exec('/usr/bin/php . escapeshellarg($filename?var=$var&var2=$var2) . ' > /dev/null');  </code>

Comment: Also if I run    <?php phpinfo() ?>    which field would include the root dir for php?

Comment: @ShaneE.Bryan Command line PHP is quite a bit different than PHP through a web server such as Apache. You're using command line PHP. Try using: ``<?php echo `which php`; ?>`` (Don't take out the backticks) to find out where your PHP is running. Or if you have direct access to a shell just type `which php` inside it.

Comment: @ShaneE.Bryan As for vars in command line PHP They'll get passed in without names, but to pass them in you would do something like: `exec('/usr/bin/php ' . escapeshellarg($filename) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($var) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($var2) . ' > /dev/null');` Then look in the `$argv` array: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: @ShaneE.Bryan Or if you want it to behave like you're used to were you can use `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` to access your variables try doing this: ``$qs = 'var= ' . $var . '&var2= ' .$var2; `export QUERY_STRING=$qs`; exec('/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/script.php > /dev/null');`` (Add a newline after each semi-colon to make it readable).

Answer (score 0):

This will actually require us to use some Javascript for an ajax call to execute our PHP and return it's data.

I prefer Jquery, which will look similar to this:

```
function callPHP(){           
     $.post('./filetocall.php', {variableid: 'id'}, function (response) {
                        $("#div_for_return_data").val(response);
                });
}
```

filetocall.php can look like anything. It's output will populate the #div_for_return_data

eg:

```
<?php echo $_GET['variableid']; ?>
```

Then just call the Jquery function from anywhere.